# This CSS works perfectly in Chrome but breaks in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

This CSS arrow works fine in chrome but breaks in IE. What's the best way to figure out how to make it work in IE9?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.nav {
    padding: 0;
    width: 115px;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid green;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;

}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div>
<div class="nav">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Breaks in IE" doesn't explain your problem.  Be more specific and you'll get better answers.

Comment: I'd have to ask that, too - I've made a jsFiddle to test and it works perfectly in IE7+, just the way it works in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/Mvweh/

Comment: adding doctype did the trick. Works in jsfiddle and my IE as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because you don't have a DOCTYPE and IE renders it in quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I agree, IE is an assisted browser, which force you to be strict ;)

Comment: Well... not sure this word was a good translation. I meant some other browsers usually try to complete missing settings, like DOCTYPE. IE needs you to write it (for good or ill)

Comment: @samsamX : Not it was a great translation. Heard it for the 1st time. LOL. "assisted", almost makes IE look like "Handicapped" that needs "assistance".

Comment: @samsamX : As I said, not only good but great. Captures the essences of the problems we face when working with IE. Must be added to the web design jokes, if they exist.